# Despite ssh-agent, TortoiseHG keeps asking for the passphrase

Tags: 12.04, mercurial, ssh-agent

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and TortoiseHG to access repositories in Bitbucket. I use ssh keys for authentication.

I run:

```
ssh-agent
```

then

```
ssh-add
```

and enter my passphrase. I can now use Mercurial and do

```
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/<username>/myrepos
```

without it aksing for my passphrase. It also works for TortoiseHG if I start it from the terminal window with

```
thg
```

However, if I start TortoiseHG by clicking the tortoise icon

[image]

I keep getting the following window *each* time I want to communicate with Bitbucket:

[image]

How do I make TortoiseHG stop asking for the passphrase all the time, even if it was started by clicking the icon?

Comment: How do you start the `TortoiseHG` program?  Have you tried to start it from the same shell you execute the command `ssh-add` from?

Comment: It works if I start TortoiseHG from the shell. I've updated my question to reflect this.